# 3D equivalent of $r=\cos(2\theta)$?

Tags: trigonometry

The function [r=cos(2*theta)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%3Dcos(2*theta)) has lobes on each axis. 
Is there a 3D version of this with 6 lobes, one pair for each axis?

I found a similar concept here: http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=4012&view=html

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-construct-a-3-dimensional-continuous-quadrifolium-but-extending-along-all-three-spacial-axes-rather-than-just-x-and-y